# If $x^3+\frac1{x^2}=1$, what is $x^3+\frac1{x^3}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

1. $x^3 + \frac1{x^2}  = 1$. Then, $x^3 + \frac1{x^3} = ~?$
2. $p + \frac1{p^2}  =  47$. Then, $p + \frac1p = ~?$

Comment: Hint Common denominator and then simplify.

Comment: sorry ..not sufficient ..!

Comment: How do you find a common denominator for the left-hand-side of the first problem?

Comment: doing l.c.m. ...!

Comment: it's seriously amusing ,.. that i found these questions in a class 8 standard question paper ..!

Comment: There is probably some mising context. For example, p+1/p^2=47 has thre different solutions: 46.9995, 0.146092, -0.14564. Substituting these values into p+1/p there will be three different results.

Comment: Looking at it more, I *strongly* suspect a transcription error in the second problem.  If it were instead $p^2+\frac{1}{p^2}=47$, then there's a very clean expression for $p+\frac1p$ that can be easily derived by a standard trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second problem (in the form: given that $p+\frac{1}{p^2}=47$, find $p+\frac1p$), we can show that in fact it's impossible for $p+\frac1p$ to be a rational number.

First, multiply the left-hand equation by $p^2$ to rewrite it as $f(p) = p^3-47p^2+1=0$.  Now, $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (by the rational root theorem it has no rational roots, and since it's a cubic polynomial, if it were going to factor at least one of the roots would be linear).  What's more, all three roots are real: $f(p)\to-\infty$ as $p\to-\infty$, $f(0)\gt 0$ by inspection, $f(46)\lt 0$ also by inspection (it's $46^2\cdot (46-47)+1$), and $f(p)\to\infty$ as $p\to\infty$ so we get roots in each of the intervals $(-\infty, 0)$, $(0,46)$ and $(46, \infty)$.  This means that there's no 'clean' formula for any of the roots, just a Cardano-style formula.

Now, suppose that $p+\frac1p = \frac ab$, for some $a$ and $b$.  Then this can be rewritten as $bp^2+b=ap$, or $g(p) = bp^2-ap+b=0$; but this implies that the cubic $f$ factors over $\mathbb{Q}$ as $f=gh$ for some linear $h$, which we've already shown impossible.  Therefore, the expression $p+\frac1p$ can't possibly be rational.

(In fact, I believe this shows something more, namely that the expression can't even be a quadratic surd — because the extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$ have to be of different degrees — but my Galois skills aren't quite strong enough to be confident in that.)

Note that if that problem were instead to find $p+\frac1p$ given that $p^2+\frac1{p^2}=47$, then it has a much cleaner answer: set $x=p+\frac1p$, multiply out to find $x^2$ and substitute the known information about $p^2+\frac1{p^2}$ to get an easy equation for $x$.  A similar approach will work for the first problem if we assume that the condition is in fact $x^2+\frac1{x^2}=1$ and the goal is to find $x^3+\frac1{x^3}$; in this case, we can set $x+\frac1x=c$.  Then $c^2=x^2+2+\frac1{x^2}$ and $c^3=x^3+3x+3\frac1x+\frac1{x^3} = x^3+\frac1{x^3}+3c$.  The first of these, along with the given information, will find you $c$, and you can then plug that information into the latter to find $x^3+\frac1{x^3}$.  I won't spoil the surprise, but it's got a cute enough catch that I suspect it must have been the intended version of the problem!

Comment: yea ,..it seems to be wrongly transcribed ..! by the way , hats off to your effort ..! nice ...:) 


do you think the 1st problem also is wrongly transcribed ?

Comment: @arnab I suspect so!  I'll edit this answer with a solution to a 'mis-transcribed' version.