# If $ x + \frac{1}{x}=3 $, what is $ x^{3} + \frac{1}{x^{3}} $ and the generalization $ x^{n} + \frac{1}{x^{n}} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

*This problem is from a math olympiad.

It is known that 
$$ x + \frac{1}{x} = 3$$
What is the value of 
$$ x^{3} + \frac{1}{x^{3}} ?$$

---

I know that we can solve for $x$ from $ x + 1/x = 3$ first, by
$$ x^{2}-3x+1 = 0$$

Which gives

$$ x = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{5} }{2} $$

Then we can relatively tedious find the values of

$$ x^{3} + \frac{1}{x^{3}} $$

> Are there better ways? Can we generalize a way for  $$ x^{n} +
>  \frac{1}{x^{n}} ? $$

Thanks.

Comment: Also similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/573232, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1465320, ...

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678650 – which shows how to generalize it for higher exponents.

Comment: I found a closed form for your question below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $$x+\frac{1}{x}=a\implies x^2-ax+1=0\implies x=\frac{1}{2} \left(a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4}\right),$$

so that $$x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}=\frac{\left(a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4}\right)^n}{2^n}+\frac{2^n}{\left(a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4}\right)^n}.$$

In your original case, you had $a=3$ and $n=3$, which gives

$$x+\frac{1}{x}=3\implies x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=\frac{8}{(\sqrt{5}+3)^3}+\frac{(\sqrt{5}+3)^3}{8}=18,$$
which is correct.

Let's try a bigger one, with $a=7$ and $n=9$,

$$x+\frac{1}{x}=7\implies x^9+\frac{1}{x^9}=\frac{512}{(7+3\sqrt{5})^9}+\frac{(7+3\sqrt{5})^9}{512}=33385282.$$

---

**Old approach**

My original solutions complicated things by using the Binomial Theorem...

$$\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^{n-k}\frac{1}{x^k}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^{n-2k}=x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{n\choose k}x^{n-2k}.$$

So if we know that
$$x+\frac{1}{x}=a,$$
then we have that
$$x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}=a^n-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{n\choose k}x^{n-2k}.$$

Since $x^2-ax+1=0$ then $x=\frac{a}{2}\pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2-4}$, so that
$$x+\frac{1}{x}=a\implies x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}=a^n-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{n\choose k}\left(\frac{a}{2}\pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2-4}\right)^{n-2k}.$$

Evaluating the finite sum gives,

$$x+\frac{1}{x}=a\implies x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}=\frac{2^n}{\left(\sqrt{a^2-4}\pm a\right)^n}+\frac{\left(\sqrt{a^2-4}\pm a\right)^n}{2^n}.$$

Comment: Thanks for this. But i dont understand why $$ x^{n-2k} = \left( \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^{2}-4}}{2} \right)^{n-2k} $$

Comment: We know from $x+\frac{1}{x}=a$ that $x^2-ax+1=0$, solving which gives us $x=\frac{a}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2-4}$.

Comment: Hmm but $$x^{2}-ax+1=0$$ is different to the binomial summation..

Comment: @Arief $x$ represents the same quantity regardless of which equation it belongs to.

Answer (score 7):

$$x + \frac1x = 3$$

Cube both sides,
$$x^3 + 3x^2 \left(\frac1x\right) +3x\left( \frac1{x^2}\right)+\frac1{x^3}=3^3 $$

$$x^3 + 3x + \frac3{x}+\frac1{x^3}=3^3 $$

Can you complete the task?

Comment: Thanks, forgot that i have also tried this.. can we generalize  a way for any natural mumber $n$?

Comment: @Arief yes. $(x+\frac1x)^n$ is a polynomial of $x+\frac1x$